# HashMap Value replacing old value even if for a new Key in java

Tags: java, collections

I have a simple observation with a Map with String keys of date format.

```
List<String> a =new ArrayList();
a.add("as");
a.add("df");
a.add("vf");
a.add("fg");
HashMap<String,List> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("2017-08-07", a);
System.out.println(""+map);
a.clear();
a.add("er");
map.put("2017-08-08", a);
System.out.println(""+map);
```

And Result is

```
{2017-08-07=[as, df, vf, fg]}
{2017-08-08=[er], 2017-08-07=[er]}
```

when i am clearing list and assign new key to my map then my old value also replacing.

But i want result be like

```
{2017-08-07=[as, df, vf, fg]}
{2017-08-08=[er], 2017-08-07=[as, df, vf, fg]}
```

How to achieve this, Any help really appreciated .
Thanks

Comment: You have only one `List`. Both entries in the map refer to the same `List`. When you put the list into the map, no copy of the list is made.

Comment: Hi deadpool, when you used "map.put("2017-08-07", a);", you stored a memroy reference object of "a"  in the "map". When you used "a.clear();" and "a.add("er");" it cleared the data stored at that location in memory and stored new data. Since "map.put("2017-08-07", a);" using the same old memory location, its value in now updated. :-)

Comment: Thank's for help.I got it.

Comment: @deadpool yes you can use list this way as suggested by Murat. Just make sure you are not using the "map" hashmap after a very long time. Rest everything will be good. Also try to use "map" as local variable as it may impact performance(which may be seen while using threads) on the basis of number of entries in "map". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call on `map.put` does not mean that it will create an entirely new value for the `List`. You put a reference to the current `List a` there and if you modify `a` it will also modify it inside the `Map`. To avoid that, create a new List.

Change this line

```
map.put("2017-08-07", a);
```

to

```
map.put("2017-08-07", new ArrayList<>(a));
```

Comment: This is the way to store the new values but make sure you are not using the HashMap after a very long time as it has a drawback. If you are using multiple "new" objects and not referring the same for a long time(considering "map" is a global variable) the GC sometimes removes random objects which results in "null" values. Observed this many times but don't know why GC do this. @MuratK. maybe you can tell.

Comment: @Aman That is way out of the scope for this question. If you really are interested in that you can open a new question.

Comment: No @MuratK. not out of scope. Because I faced this problem and spent many debugging hours on it, I just wanted to share the information only. :-)

Comment: @Aman  can you share more information regarding this.If i use new list for every keys in a map.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are modifying the same instance of list, hence the modifications will effect everywhere. Create a new list if you want to have separate results otherwise you lost all the  data everywhere when you clear it.

```
map.put("2017-08-07", a);
System.out.println(""+map);
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.add("er");
map.put("2017-08-08", b);
System.out.println(""+map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a new List to map, so *a* won't be linked.

```
map.put("2017-08-07", new List<String>(a));
```